# May I use comma to avoid redundancy in expressions?

Tags: definition

Is it generally possible to write
$$1\leq k,l\leq 8$$
instead of 
$$1\leq k\leq8\quad \mathrm{and} \quad 1\leq l\leq 8$$
to avoid redundancy?

Comment: Yes, yes you may. It's done all the time.

Comment: There is also the logical "and" symbol $\land$ which you could use.

Comment: As long as we are trying to improve readability... $\ell$ (\ell) looks *much* better than $l$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely, a lot of people do it all the time.

Just be careful to avoid confusion between

$$1\leq l,k\leq 8$$

and

$$1\leq l<k\leq 8.$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but be sure that the space after the comma is thin (which is the TeX default). Thus, if we were to write (rather unnaturally) "$1\leqslant k,\;$ $l\leqslant8,\;$ and $m\leqslant3$", the reader would be uncertain as to whether the restrictions on $k$ and $l$ applied respectively or to both.